# Get part of a string with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How might I figure out the category based on the CSS classes on the body please? Here is the body element:

```
<body class="archive category category-basketball category-23872 content-sidebar">
```

I want to output DFP page targeting for a category archive page. The format for the DFP page targeting code is

```
googletag.pubads().setTargeting( "category", "basketball" );
```

Therefore, I want to check for the existence of a `category-{something}` where `{something}` is the value for the category. Unfortunately, the 2nd `category-23872` complicates the issue.

Appreciate any help and ideas. Thanks

Comment: look up regular expressions.

Comment: Do you want to check for all `category-FOOBAR` where `FOOBAR != integer`? As pointed out by @DanielA.White [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) should be doing that magic for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions and `match()`.

```js
let str =  `<body class="archive category category-basketball category-23872 content-sidebar">`;
let res = str.match(/category-[^\s0-9]+/g)
console.log(res)
```

Comment: I think he meant except `category-23872`

Comment: @iLuvLogix Fixed that

Comment: sweet - that looks better now ;)